# Binding multiple input models

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind a ng-model this way:

```
      <md-list-item ng-repeat="reply in replies">
        <md-input-container flex style="margin-top:-7px;" ng-show="replyLink">
          <label>Your reply ...</label>
          <input ng-model="replyMsg" ng-enter="addReply(reply.id)">
        </md-input-container>
      </md-list-item>
```

From the other side:

```
 $scope.replyMsg...
```

Using this, when I change the value of one ng-model and log the content of `replyMsg`, I get `undefined` as output message. How do I fix that?

I've tried to make it `ng-model="replyMsg{{$index}}"`, but, I wasn't able to find out how to deal with this model name in the other side using $scope.

Any brilliant suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in this way . every reply will contain their reply msz.

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="reply in replies">
        <md-input-container flex style="margin-top:-7px;" ng-show="replyLink">
          <label>Your reply ...</label>
          <input ng-model="reply.replyMsg" ng-enter="addReply(reply.id)">
        </md-input-container>
      </md-list-item>
```

Comment: it still the same. I think that is because that there are multiple inputs binding with the same ng-model. Is there another alternative?

Comment: `$scope.reply.replyMsg`, I've got `undefined` as output message.

Comment: have you typed anything before accessing ??

Comment: yes, and after that I've pressed on the `Enter` key.

Comment: after filling first input do like this $scope.replies[0].replyMsg

Comment: it still the same. Concerning my conrtoller. the posted snippet code is suffisiant i think

Comment: but, now how do I know which element of the array which was filled!

Comment: Do I need to apply a test? that wouldn't be efficient as solution.

Comment: you can get that from a id keep an unique id in replies

Answer (score 0):

I made simple plunker of that hope this helps.

```
`http://plnkr.co/edit/OUqh5l1omH9Tgv6xAyBO?p=preview`
```